# Invalid block tag on line 1: 'set'. Did you forget to register or load this tag

Tags: django, jinja2

page.html

```
{% set x = 5 %}
```

I am getting the error below when running the website.

> Invalid block tag on line 1: 'set'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: Where did this `{% set ... %}` comes from?

Comment: Did you enable Jinja2 in Django?

Comment: I didn't get you.

Comment: @blhsing how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try the "with" tag:

```
{% with x=1 %}
```

[With docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

or:

```
{% with "5" as x %}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you really want to do. Maybe custom template tag is what you are looking for: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

Comment: with custom template tag you must load the template tag in every page... with context processors you can let it global to entire application without needing to import in everypage